# ICredentialProvider COM definition interface

Tags: c#, .net, windows, winapi, credential-providers

I need to implement a custom Credential Provider in C#, but I am struggling to find the COM interface definition.

Have any of you managed to do so?

My idea is to use such provider to create an auto logon mechanism triggered from a Windows Service (developed in C#).

Cheers,

Comment: http://pgina.org will make this easier.

Comment: This is the documentation for the [ICredentialProvider](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb776042.aspx) interface. Requires that you know COM, and how to translate interface implementations to C#.

Comment: @AlexK. i cannot use pGina because this will require another service that replaces the actual logon process. Some end users would not allow that. The least intrusive option is a COM provider that works alongside whatever is that the user has on his end.

Comment: @IInspectable that is the thing. I am having a hard time translating that interface to COM... any directions you can point me to?

Comment: @RobsonFelix I have made an example C# implementation of CredentialsProvider - you can find it here: https://github.com/phaetto/windows-credentials-provider

Comment: @AlexanderMantzoukas I will look into it and let you know how it went. Thanks man!